# Definition of 'cofiber' of a module homomorphism

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory, modules, cofibrations

Suppose I have a commutative unital ring $R$ and an element $a\in R$. Let $\phi:R\to R$ be the map $\phi(b):=ab$.

I have been asked to find the *cofiber* of this map, with no context given (the text I am using is not publicly available). I cannot make sense of what I have read online regarding cofibers [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofibration) or [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cofiber) (there is no topology involved in what I am doing right now, and most of the definitions seem to refer to homotopy theory).

What might be meant by the cofiber? It looks like it has something to do with pushout diagrams but I cannot quite make sense of this.

Comment: You can treat it as a synonym for cokernel. If you are doing homological algebra then the answer would be different.